# Select records from today, this week, this month php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I imagine this is pretty simple, but can't figure it out. I'm trying to make a few pages - one which will contain results selected from my mysql db's table for today, this week, and this month. The dates are entered when the record is created with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. Here's what I have so far:

day  where date>(date-(60*60*24))

```
 "SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date>(date-(60*60*24)) ORDER BY score DESC"
```

week  where date>(date-(60*60*24*7))

```
 "SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date>(date-(60*60*24*7)) ORDER BY score DESC"
```

month (30 days)   where date>(date-(60*60*24*30))

```
 "SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date>(date-(60*60*24*30)) ORDER BY score DESC"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Assuming your date column is an actual MySQL date column:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY score DESC;        
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY score DESC;
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: ostgard, hi thanks for replying - i'm not sure. Here is how I enter the date: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: From the MySQL prompt, type `DESCRIBE jokes;` and look at the Type of the date field. What is it?

Comment: So I changed it to datetime and didn't do anything and it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: @NathanOstgard I am trying the same query for a month...but adding another AND and its not working...like this: SELECT id,title,start_date FROM events WHERE start_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND city = 'Khobar' ORDER BY start_date DESC....any idea why?

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a floating result set, for instance if you subtract 1 day from now, it will be a different result set at 2am as compared to the result set from 8pm?

Comment: I want to count visitors of current month, for which I'd modified your query as: `select count(*) as total from visitors where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` but I'm not getting total of this month, instead its result is the total number of visitors till date

Comment: This will just subtract 1 week right? What about the current week?

Comment: Can any one help how fetch yesterday date record also ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(date) = DAY(NOW())-1;   for yesterday record

Comment: I'm confused: does this actually show the data for THIS week or MAX 1 week ago?

Answer (score 75):

Try using date and time functions (MONTH(), YEAR(), DAY(), [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html))

This week:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Last week:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())-1;
```

Comment: It must do a cast internally because this just kills performance on large result sets.

Comment: What happends if the current week is week 1? does it automaticly take the last week of the previous year?

Comment: this is the best answer by far

Comment: The best answer, please update it to 
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(now());
to exclude older years' data.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is the most correct way to do it.

Answer (score 40):

Current month:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW());
```

Current week:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Current day:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(date) = DAY(NOW());
```

This will select only current month, really week and really only today :-)

Comment: Thanks very much. This solution worked perfect for me when creating some custom leader boards.

Comment: For current week use `YEARWEEK`, because if you have data in your table from year 2016, 2017 and 2018 with the same week date for example, it will only show the 2018 week data. With `WEEKOFYEAR` it will show week data from 2016, 2017 and 2018.

Answer (score 9):

Nathan's answer will give you jokes from last 24, 168, and 744 hours, NOT the jokes from today, this week, this month.  If that's what you want, great, but I think you might be looking for something different.

Using his code, at noon, you will get the jokes beginning yesterday at noon, and ending today at noon.  If you really want today's jokes, try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY score DESC;
```

You would have to do something a little different from current week, month, etc., but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody seems to refer to date being a column in the table.
I dont think this is good practice. The word date might just be a keyword in some coding language (maybe Oracle) so please change the columnname date to maybe JDate.
So will the following work better:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE JDate >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY JScore DESC;
```

So we have a table called Jokes with columns JScore and JDate.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution for "today" is:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

Nathan's answer is very close however it will return a floating result set.  As the time shifts, records will float off of and onto the result set.  Using the `DATE()` function on `NOW()` will strip the time element from the date creating a static result set.  Since the `date()` function is applied to `now()` instead of the actual `date` column performance should be higher since applying a function such as `date()` to a date column inhibits MySql's ability to use an index.

To keep the result set static use:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
ORDER BY score DESC;

SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY score DESC;

SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Yes, but this is still not this week - if week starts on monday, and we will do this select in tuesday, we will get jokes from last tuesday (last week), not this monday, cause this is this week by right logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `NOW()` function is incorrect for getting time difference. Because by `NOW()` function every time your are calculating the past 24 hours.
You must use `CURDATE()` instead.

```
    function your_function($time, $your_date) {
    if ($time == 'today') {
        $timeSQL = ' Date($your_date)= CURDATE()';
    }
    if ($time == 'week') {
        $timeSQL = ' YEARWEEK($your_date)= YEARWEEK(CURDATE())';
    }
    if ($time == 'month') {
        $timeSQL = ' Year($your_date)=Year(CURDATE()) AND Month(`your_date`)= Month(CURDATE())';
    }

    $Sql = "SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE ".$timeSQL
    return $Result = $this->db->query($Sql)->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solution will help you select only current month, current week and only today

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE games.published_gm = 1 AND YEAR(addedon_gm) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(addedon_gm) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(addedon_gm) = DAY(NOW()) ORDER BY addedon_gm DESC;
```

For Weekly added posts:

```
WEEKOFYEAR(addedon_gm) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
```

For Monthly added posts:

```
MONTH(addedon_gm) = MONTH(NOW())
```

For Yearly added posts:

```
YEAR(addedon_gm) = YEAR(NOW())
```

you'll get the accurate results where show only the games added today, otherwise you may display: "No New Games Found For Today". Using ShowIF recordset is empty transaction.

Comment: Please explain your solution - don't just post code.

Answer (score 0):

To get last week's data in MySQL. This works for me even across the year boundries.

```sql
select * from orders_order where YEARWEEK(my_date_field)= YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK));
```

To get current week's data

```sql
select * from orders_order where YEARWEEK(date_sold)= YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do like that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY score DESC;        
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY score DESC;
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Just to add here that: 
this query works fine but it does not get data from current week like if today is Tuesday then it should only show data of Monday and Tuesday but it fetches for last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sum(if(DATE(dDate)=DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),earning,null)) astodays,
sum(if(YEARWEEK(dDate)=YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE),earning,null)) as weeks,
IF((MONTH(dDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AND YEAR(dDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())),sum(earning),0) AS months,
IF(YEAR(dDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),sum(earning),0) AS years,
sum(fAdminFinalEarning) as total_earning FROM `earning`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can do same thing using single query

```
SELECT sum(if(DATE(dDate)=DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),earning,null)) astodays,
       sum(if(YEARWEEK(dDate)=YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE),earning,null)) as weeks, 
       IF((MONTH(dDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AND YEAR(dDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())),sum(earning),0) AS months,
       IF(YEAR(dDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),sum(earning),0) AS years, 
       sum(fAdminFinalEarning) as total_earning FROM `earning`
```

Hope this works.